# How is Windows 7 Kernel only 25 MB?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, monolithic

I found out that Windows has a monolithic kernel : [Winodws 7 to feature 25 MB Kernel](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-news-digest/windows-7-to-feature-a-25-mb-kernel/)

As per wikipedia:  A monolithic kernel is an operating system architecture where the entire operating system is working in kernel space.

So how does Windows 7 Kernel has 25 MB size and still be monolithic ?

Comment: "MinWin does not have a graphical interface and will not be productized." - It is very reduced Windows. So it kernel could be small.

Comment: So you are saying that other things are just system programs in the user space ?

Comment: I say nothing about user space programs. 25MB - is the size of the kernel only.

Comment: It's not a monolithic kernel: "The new microkernel will be used internally for all upcoming versions of Windows". Also, the article makes a weird comparison: 4GB "core" (memory footprint) vs 25 MB "size" (of the binary).